# Average Value of a Function Jog of Memory

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I understand that the average value formulation is the following: \begin{equation} f_{avg} = \frac{\int_{a}^b f(x)\ dx}{b-a} \end{equation}.
I have been given this problem:

## Problem

Water is run at a constant rate of 1 cubic feet per minute to fill a cylindrical tank of radius 3 feet, and height 5 feet. Assuming that the tank is initially empty, make a conjecture about the average weight of the water in the tank over the time period required to fill it, and then check your conjecture by integrating.[Take the weight density of the water to be 62.4 pounds per cubic feet.]

## My Approach

I believe I have to first get the volume of the shape which is: \begin{equation} V=\pi r^2 h \end{equation}
Which gives me a volume of $V=45\pi$
\begin{equation}V(t)= t \end{equation}
Since it says at a constant rate of 1 cubic feet per minute.

Is this answer acceptable \begin{equation}\frac{\int_{0}^{45\pi} 62.4\cdot V(t) dt}{45\pi-0} \end{equation}
It gets me the answer in the back of the text book but I am unsure, I believe this just rigged the problem to be right.

Comment: If you are unsure, you should explain the reasoning behind your answer.  What is $x$ supposed to represent?  Yes, the result is correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan The volume in the tank, which is a linear function t, or 1 cubic feet per minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to state that you got the time $T$ required for filling the tank (upper limit in the integral) by solving equation:

$$ V(T) = 45 \pi. $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is perhaps a more intuitive way of answering it:

Initially the tank is empty (and so is the weight). Since the influx rate is constant, the weight increases linearly. Hence average weight is that of the half tank, which is what my conjecture would be.